# How do I clear the warning "Map Service Token Not Specified" on the Map?

Tags: .net, gps, win-universal-app

I am developing a Universal Windows App. In that I used `Map` to display the user's current location details on a map.

The user location is getting displayed successfully, however on the map a warning message is also displayed:

> Map Service Token Not Specified

I have already specified map service token to the map!

How do I clear the warning message `Map Service Token Not Specified` that appears on the map?

Answer (score 1):

To properly get the Map Token for Universal Windows 10 App please go through below steps. I have done them and everything is working properly.

1. Visit [Bing Maps Dev Center](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/#)
2. Sign in with your Microsoft account and on the top select "My account" -> "My Keys":

[image]

3. Select "Click here to create a new key":

[image]

4. Now you have to fill three required fields:
   a. "Application name"
   b. "Key type" -> set it to basic
   c. "Application type" -> set it to Universal Windows App

Then click "Create".

[image]

5.Once you do it below you should see generated key:

[image]

Please let me know if after these steps problem remains.